# Understanding a java OO

Tags: java, oop

I am a beginner in JAVA OO ... and I faced a code recently, and I have a question:

I have two classes code:

```
public class QaaVO extends AbstractValueObject<Timestamp>{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -9216296526667849732L;

private Timestamp id;
private String textMessage;
private String userCode;
    private Long areaId;
private Long statusID;
private Timestamp adId;
public Timestamp getAdId() {

    //getters and setters
    }
```

And this one:

```
public class AdVO extends AbstractValueObject<Timestamp>{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7122369724482287295L;

private Timestamp id;
private String userCode;
private String userName;
private String email;
private String emailCc;
private String telephone; 
private String dealerCode;
private int score;
private String dateOpen;
private Date dateClose;

private List<String> qaaVO;

    getters and setter;

    }
```

My question is... why do I need the `private List<String> qaaVO` in the AdVO class?

Comment: So you can have a list of strings called `qaaVO`?

Comment: Well, you don't **need** it, unless it's being used.

Comment: Dave's comment is spot on.  You only 'need' that field insofar as you want to store a list of Strings, and you feel that `qaaVO` is a sensible name for this list.

Comment: But it isn't referenced to the QaaVO class?

Comment: Just because the qaaVO variable name is similar to the class name QaaVO doesn't necessarily mean they are related at all.  In particular, professors love to use similar but different names in tests and exams just to screw you up.

Comment: No, there is nothing in that code that links or reference or establishes any relationship between QaaVO and qaaVO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QaaVO and AdVO are as far as I can see two unrelated classes.

In the AdVO you're probably going to use a lot of Strings,
hence the List. The name is the same yes, but it's declared as a list, not as an Object of QaaVO.